# How to define conv2D size based on input shape

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I don't understand how to measure size of Conv2D, pool_size of MaxPooling2D etc. for building a CNN? For example, I saw a tutorial where they run this when the **image size** is `28*28`:

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

Now I am working with a dataset where **image size** is **100*100**. So, I tried to build the model like the example:

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(100,100,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='softmax'))
```

But, I am not getting a decent result at all:

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

n=100   # to reduce time in slow pc

model.fit(X_train_4d[:n], y_train_categorical[:n], 
          batch_size=32, epochs=5, verbose=1)

loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test_4d[:n], y_test_categorical[:n], verbose=0)
print('\nTest Acc: ', accuracy)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/5
100/100 [==============================] - 12s 121ms/step - loss: 6.0578 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/5
100/100 [==============================] - 10s 96ms/step - loss: 4.0280 - accuracy: 0.1000
Epoch 3/5
100/100 [==============================] - 9s 94ms/step - loss: 3.7660 - accuracy: 0.3000
Epoch 4/5
100/100 [==============================] - 9s 94ms/step - loss: 3.2143 - accuracy: 0.3600
Epoch 5/5
100/100 [==============================] - 10s 103ms/step - loss: 2.3389 - accuracy: 0.4000

Test Acc:  0.25999999046325684
```

So, I think for different `input_shape`, size of grid, dense should be different? But, I don't understand which size should we choose for which shape?

Comment: I assume you have 64 classes in 100*100 image problem. But I believe the same NN architecture that was used in 28*28 problem should have worked quite well in 100*100 case, and certainly would not perform so poorly to say 'not getting a decent result at all'. Do you have the data with you?

Comment: Yes, I have 64 classes (for 100*100 image) and I have the data with me.

Comment: You would need to specify a validation set, either using `validation_split` or `validation_data` argument in `model.fit()` and observe whether validation loss is decreasing. It seems like your model is not trained enough with 5 epochs

Comment: I splitted my dataset like this way: `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, targetLabel, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)` and then reshape X,y as needed. I am new at ml. I don't understand how to use properly `validation_split` or `validation_data` argument in `model.fit()`. Can you please show me a simple & easy to understand example?

Comment: okay, skipping `validation_data` for now. I have increased the epochs to 20. So, I am getting high accuracy on training data: `100/100 [==============================] - 10s 99ms/step - loss: 0.0287 - accuracy: 1.0000` But, when I am evaluating the model on test, I am getting poor accuracy on test again. `loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test_4d[:n], y_test_categorical[:n], verbose=0)` `Loss:  4.308310394287109 
Acc:  0.3499999940395355` Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: This is because the model is overfitting. You can define `validation_split=0.2` argument in `model.fit()` which would take out 20% of training data as validation. Then, when training you would have a validation loss. You need to stop the training once validation loss hits minimum to prevent overfitting.

Comment: By the way, achieving a high accuracy with 64 classes would be quite hard, unless the classes are clearly separable and the dataset is of good quality and sufficient (e.g. over 10000 samples at least). I will add this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at your code, it seems you have 64 classes. In order to train a model with such high number of classes, we need to at least have sufficient number of examples per class (say 10) to obtain a reasonable classification accuracy. I believe the low accuracy you obtain for the test set is not majorly because of anything wrong in the model parameters, rather it is because of limited amount of data.

I see that you have limited your training data by setting `n=100` which is obviously not enough to train the model. I would assume you need to have at least 10000 total data samples in the database to obtain an acceptable classification accuracy. Use the full database and give it some time to train.

Moreover, you would need to specify some validation data to observe how the model performs throughout training. For example, this can easily be done by setting `validation_split=0.2` argument in `model.fit()` which would take out 20% of training data for validation. Then you would have a validation loss which should be constantly monitored and the training should be stopped when validation loss hits a minimum in order to prevent overfitting.

Comment: "I see that you have limited your training data by setting n=100 which is obviously not enough to train the model." Actually, this line has helped me to get better accuracy. I have used previous code (`epochs=5`, no validation set on `model.fit`) and removed the limit `n=100`. It took at least 15 minutes with the number of my total sample (`1945`). Now, I am getting a decent accuracy on test: `0.81999`